# How to prevent content page from being updated when the master page is updated?

Tags: c#

I've an UpdatePanel in the master page and another one in the content page. When I use Timer to refresh the master page, the content page, which has its own Timer, is updated, too.

Question 1: How can I prevent the refresh in the master page from updating the content page?

Question 2: The Timer interval in the content page, is set at 60000. When the page is loaded, I've to wait 60000 to see the GridView data displayed. How to make it display data as soon aas the page is loaded and then refresh the data every 60000?

Site.Master:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMouseRegion" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:Timer runat="server" id="SiteMasterTimer" Interval="10000" OnTick="SiteMasterTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer> 

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMouseRegion" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>  
// mouse region to be updated
```

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="DisplayResultsScriptManager" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>

<asp:Timer ID="DisplayResultsTimer" Interval="60000" Enabled="true" runat="server" OnTick="DisplayResultsTimer_Tick"> 
</asp:Timer> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DisplayResultsUpdatePanel" runat="server" >
   <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DisplayResultsTimer" />  
   </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>

    // GridView to be updated
```

Answer (score 0):

For the updatePanels, set UpdateMode to [Conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155262.aspx)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMouseRegion" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

For more information: [Creating a Simple ASP.NET Page with Multiple UpdatePanel Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398867.aspx)